# Goal seek exit year rises infinitely

Tags: vba, excel

I am brand new to VBA.  I have a basic excel 2010 project finance model I made specifically for practicing goal seek macros and learning some VBA. I used this macro (taken from a workbook made by someone else) and successfully adapted it to my own to find the PPA rate by entering the desired IRR.

However, I am trying to adapt it again to find the exit year by entering desired IRR, and it causes the exit year to increase infinitely.  Ideally I want it to only be able to seek for a year within a specified range and only round numbers (ie years 1-25 only)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


Equity_IRR_New = Range("D21").Value
Equity_IRR_Old = Range("C23").Value
Tariff_New = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C21").Value
Tariff_Old = 0
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C21").Value = 100000'
If (Equity_IRR_New < Equity_IRR_Old) Then
    Do Until (Equity_IRR_New >= Equity_IRR_Old)
        ExitYr_Old = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C21").Value
        ExitYr_New = ExitYr_Old * (0.999)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C21").Value = ExitYr_New
        Equity_IRR_Old = Range("C23").Value
    Loop
End If

If (Equity_IRR_New > Equity_IRR_Old) Then
    Do Until (Equity_IRR_New <= Equity_IRR_Old)
        ExitYr_Old = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C21").Value
        ExitYr_New = ExitYr_Old * (1.001)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C21").Value = ExitYr_New
        Equity_IRR_Old = Range("C23").Value
    Loop
End If

Range("C21").Value = ExitYr_New


End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a programming service.  What part of this code isn't working, and how is it failing?

Comment: @hosch250 -1 to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your loop condition is looking for `Equity_IRR_New <= Equity_IRR_Old`, and that condition will never be met since you're INCREASING `Equity_IRR_New` in each loop iteration.

The way you have it setup based on your comment "'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C21").Value = 100000'", it will only enter the second "if" block, i.e.:

```
If (Equity_IRR_New > Equity_IRR_Old) Then
    Do Until (Equity_IRR_New <= Equity_IRR_Old)
        ExitYr_Old = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C21").Value
        ExitYr_New = ExitYr_Old * (1.001)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C21").Value = ExitYr_New
        Equity_IRR_Old = Range("C23").Value
    Loop
End If
```

As I said above, the value of `Equity_IRR_New` is ever increasing with every loop, because of the statement `ExitYr_New = ExitYr_Old * (1.001)`, and therefore, if it's not less than or equal to `Equity_IRR_Old` to start of with, it will never be.  What is the initial value in cell "C23"?